# How to svn dump a specific folder and load it into a specific location

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svnadmin

So here's the story, I have the following svn repos -

```
Fruit
 - Banana
   - trunk
 - Mango

Vegetables
 - Potato
   - trunk
 - Mango
   - trunk
```

As it turns out, this whole time we've been using the wrong repo (Vegetables) for our Mango project, and we have an existing Mango folder in the Fruit repo. So my mission is to get folder Vegetables\Mango\trunk into Fruit\Mango. Here is my attempt -

```
// I dump the vegetables repo
svnadmin dump C:\Repos\Vegetables > Vegetables.dump 

// I then filter the dump to only include Mango/trunk
svndumpfilter --drop-empty-revs --renumber-revs include Mango/trunk < Vegetables.dump > Mango-trunk.dump

// Finally, I load the filtered dump file into the Fruit/Mango
svnadmin load C:\Repos\Fruit --parent-dir Mango < Mango-trunk.dump
```

The resulting Fruit repo was the following -

```
Fruit
 - Banana
   - trunk
 - Mango
   - Mango
     - trunk
```

This is obviously hypothetical but it reflects the issue I am having now. I can't figure how to migrate the trunk folder **alone** without its parent directories. I even attempted to dumpfilter the filtered dump based on my incorrect assumptions of the file system, but that was to no avail. I need hints for performing that exact task, suggested alternatives won't help me, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

The SVN manual has an [example](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering) of how to move a top-level directory into its own repository, which you should be able to adapt to your situation.

The basic process is to edit your dump file manually before loading it with `svnadmin load`. First, remove the leading `Mango/` from the `Node-path` and `Node-copyfrom-path` headers in the dump file. Then, remove the section of the dump file that creates the `Mango` directory. It will look something like this:

```
Node-path: Mango
Node-action: add
Node-kind: dir
Content-length: 0
```

But note the following:

> **Warning**
>
> If you do plan on manually editing the dump file to remove a top-level directory, make sure your editor is not set to automatically convert end-of-line characters to the native format (e.g., `\r\n` to `\n`), as the content will then not agree with the metadata. This will render the dump file useless.

Now you can load the dump file.